# Why i can't call function when assigned to $scope in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.clazzDialog = function openClazzDialog(event) {...};
```

I'm using ui-router. When call {{!!clazzDialog}} inside template get false. Why it's not defined?? Another functions get true. I even tried to rename. delete function's body. But it doesn't worked.

Comment: You can use`{{ !!classDialog()}}`

Comment: I try to reproduce the problem and i can't. can you create a codepen with the problem?

Comment: Check if you can access it correctly, I cant reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

For a function defined on $scope, you wouldn't want to rename the function like you are doing.

```
$scope.clazzDialog = function openClazzDialog(event) {...};
```

You would only want to provide a name on the $scope so it would look something like this:

```
$scope.clazzDialog = function(event) {...};
```

Comment: I tried. Ok, finally, I created another controller where copied that code and it works. I'm so frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

I created another controller with the same code and it works, now I believ that angular is magic.